# How to have socket.io on a custom Node server accept CORS requests?

Tags: socket.io, cors

I have a CORS error on a `socket.io` server:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://dev.learnintouch.com:9001/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NbAVesU' from origin 'http://dev.learnintouch.com:83' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I do use the `cors` properties:

```
module.exports.io = socketio(httpsServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://dev.learnintouch.com:83'
  }
});
```

I also tried the `*` property:

```
module.exports.io = socketio(httpsServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: [
      'GET',
      'POST'
    ],
    allowedHeaders: [],
    credentials: true
  }
});
```

but the error is the exact same.

Here is what the log has to say:

```
The NodeJS HTTP server [port: 9001] is listening...
{
  redis: { hostname: 'redis', port: 6379 },
  socketio: { port: 9001, sslport: 9002 },
  ssl: {
    path: '/usr/local/learnintouch/letsencrypt/',
    key: 'current-privkey.pem',
    certificate: 'current-cert.pem',
    chain: 'current-fullchain.pem'
  }
}
The virtual host DOESN'T have an SSL private key
Configuring the server for HTTP
The HTTP server is used by the healthcheck even if the socket is served on the HTTPS server
Server {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _nsps: Map {
    '/' => Namespace {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      sockets: Map {},
      _fns: [],
      _ids: 0,
      server: [Circular],
      name: '/',
      adapter: [Adapter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
  },
  parentNsps: Map {},
  _path: '/socket.io',
  clientPathRegex: /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.min|\.msgpack\.min)?\.js(\.map)?$/,
  _connectTimeout: 45000,
  _serveClient: true,
  _parser: {
    protocol: 5,
    PacketType: {
      '0': 'CONNECT',
      '1': 'DISCONNECT',
      '2': 'EVENT',
      '3': 'ACK',
      '4': 'CONNECT_ERROR',
      '5': 'BINARY_EVENT',
      '6': 'BINARY_ACK',
      CONNECT: 0,
      DISCONNECT: 1,
      EVENT: 2,
      ACK: 3,
      CONNECT_ERROR: 4,
      BINARY_EVENT: 5,
      BINARY_ACK: 6
    },
    Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
    Decoder: [Function: Decoder]
  },
  encoder: Encoder {},
  _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
  sockets: Namespace {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    sockets: Map {},
    _fns: [],
    _ids: 0,
    server: [Circular],
    name: '/',
    adapter: Adapter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      nsp: [Circular],
      rooms: Map {},
      sids: Map {},
      encoder: Encoder {},
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  opts: { cors: { origin: 'http://dev.learnintouch.com:83' } },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

My `socket.io.min.js` version is:

```
/*!
 * Socket.IO v4.0.1
 * (c) 2014-2021 Guillermo Rauch
 * Released under the MIT License.
 */
```

I `npm` installed `cors` and added a `require` but I'm not sure that is needed though.

For additional information, the server implementation:

```
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var cors = require('cors');
var connect = require('connect');
var cookie = require('cookie');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var redis = require('redis');
var ioredis = require('socket.io-redis');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var utils = require('./utils.js');
var config = require('./config');

var sslKey = '';
var sslCertificate = '';
var sslChain = '';
if (fs.existsSync(config.ssl.path + config.ssl.key)) {
  sslKey = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(config.ssl.path + config.ssl.key));
  sslCertificate = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(config.ssl.path + config.ssl.certificate));
  sslChain = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(config.ssl.path + config.ssl.chain));
  console.log("The virtual host HAS an SSL private key");
} else {
  console.log("The virtual host DOESN'T have an SSL private key");
}

console.log("Configuring the server for HTTP");
console.log("The HTTP server is used by the healthcheck even if the socket is served on the HTTPS server");
var httpServer = http.createServer(utils.httpHandler);
httpServer.listen(config.socketio.port, function() {
  console.log('The NodeJS HTTP server [port: ' + config.socketio.port + '] is listening...');
});

if (sslKey) {
  console.log("Configuring the server for HTTPS");
  var options = {
    key: sslKey,
    cert: sslCertificate,
    ca: sslChain,
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  };
  var httpsServer = https.createServer(options, utils.httpHandler);
  httpsServer.listen(config.socketio.sslport, function() {
    console.log('The NodeJS HTTPS server [port: ' + config.socketio.sslport + '] is listening...');
  });
}

module.exports.io = socketio(httpsServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    methods: [
      'GET',
      'POST'
    ],
    allowedHeaders: [],
    credentials: true
  }
});
console.log(module.exports.io);

module.exports.io.adapter(ioredis({ host: config.redis.hostname, port: config.redis.port }));
var redisClient = redis.createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.hostname);

module.exports.io.use(function (socket, handler) {
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) {
    socket.request.cookies = cookie.parse(decodeURIComponent(socket.request.headers.cookie));
    socket.request.sessionID = socket.request.cookies['PHPSESSID'];
    socket.request.socketSessionId = socket.request.cookies['socketSessionId'];
    console.log("Authorization attempt with sessionID: " + socket.request.sessionID + " and socketSessionId: " + socket.request.socketSessionId);
    redisClient.get("PHPREDIS_SESSION:" + socket.request.sessionID, function (error, reply) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("The redis client had an error: " + error);
        return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because the redis client had an error.'));
      } else if (!reply) {
        console.log('The connection was refused because the redis client did not find the sessionID.');
        return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because the redis client did not find the sessionID.'));
      } else {
        var redisSocketSessionId = utils.getRedisValue(reply, "socketSessionId");
        if ('undefined' == typeof socket.request.socketSessionId || redisSocketSessionId != socket.request.socketSessionId) {
          console.log('The connection was refused because the socketSessionId was invalid.');
          return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because the socketSessionId was invalid.'));
        } else {
          console.log('The connection was granted.');
          handler();
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('The connection was refused because no cookie was transmitted.');
    return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because no cookie was transmitted.'));
  }
});
```

UPDATE: The `utils.js` file:

```
var formidable = require('formidable');

Array.prototype.contains = function(k, callback) {
  var self = this;
  return (function check(i) {
    if (i >= self.length) {
      return callback(false);
    }
    if (self[i] === k) {
      return callback(true);
    }
    return process.nextTick(check.bind(null, i+1));
  }(0));
};

module.exports.isEmpty = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

module.exports.getRedisValue = function(data, name) {
  var redisBits = data.split(";");
  for (var i in redisBits) {
    if (redisBits.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      if (redisBits[i].substring(0, name.length) == name) {
        var value = redisBits[i].split("|")[1].split(":")[2].replace("\"", "").replace("\"", "");
        return(value);
      }
    }
  }
};

// Handle http requests sent to the Node.js server
module.exports.httpHandler = function(req, res) {
  switch(req.url) {
    case '/ping':
      if (req.method == 'GET') {
//        console.log("Received a [200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('');
      }
      break;
    case '/push':
      if (req.method == 'POST') {
//        console.log("Received a [200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
        form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(e, fields, files) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
          res.end('');
          httpHandleServerPostRequest(fields);
        });
      }
      break;
    default:
      send404(res);
  };
};

send404 = function(res) {
  res.writeHead(404);
  res.write('404');
  res.end();
};
```

Comment: Could you add the code of your utils.js file? I want to check the content of utils.httpHandler.

Comment: And yes you don't need the require("cors");

Comment: @AlbertThompson But I do need the `npm install cors` ?

Comment: Yes you need the npm install cors

Answer (score 0):

I added headers in my HTTP server handler and it solved the issue:

```
// Handle http requests sent to the Node.js server
module.exports.httpHandler = function(req, res, next) {
  // Allow CORS
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");

  switch(req.url) {
    case '/ping':
      if (req.method == 'GET') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('');
      }
      break;
    case '/push':
      if (req.method == 'POST') {
        form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function(e, fields, files) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
          res.end('');
          httpHandleServerPostRequest(fields);
        });
      }
      break;
    default:
  };
};
```