# The NodeJS socket.io server is not responding

Tags: node.js, socket.io

You can see for yourself that the request hangs:

```
curl "http://europasprak.com:9001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"
```

It also hangs when sending the request from the server machine itself:

```
curl "http://localhost:9001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"
```

I'm trying to create a `socket.io` server following the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/).

I have the NodeJS socket server:

```
var http = require('http');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var httpServer = http.createServer(utils.httpHandler);
httpServer.listen(config.socketio.port, function() {
  console.log('The NodeJS HTTP server [port: ' + config.socketio.port + '] is listening...');
});
```

Using the DEBUG variable to start the server as in:

```
DEBUG=socket* node /usr/local/learnintouch/engine/api/js/socket/elearning-server.js 2>&1 >> /usr/local/learnintouch/logs/nodejs.log
```

shows:

```
  socket.io:server creating engine.io instance with opts {"cors":{"origin":"*"},"path":"/socket.io"} +2ms
  socket.io:server attaching client serving req handler +5ms
  socket.io:server initializing namespace / +1ms
  socket.io:server initializing namespace /elearning +10ms
```

The NodeJS log shows:

```
The NodeJS HTTP server [port: 9001] is listening...
```

The server object is:

```
{
  io: Server {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _nsps: Map { '/' => [Namespace] },
    parentNsps: Map {},
    _path: '/socket.io',
    clientPathRegex: /^\/socket\.io\/socket\.io(\.min|\.msgpack\.min)?\.js(\.map)?$/,
    _connectTimeout: 45000,
    _serveClient: true,
    _parser: {
      protocol: 5,
      PacketType: [Object],
      Encoder: [Function: Encoder],
      Decoder: [Function: Decoder]
    },
    encoder: Encoder {},
    _adapter: [Function],
    sockets: Namespace {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      sockets: Map {},
      _fns: [Array],
      _ids: 0,
      server: [Circular],
      name: '/',
      adapter: [RedisAdapter],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    opts: { cors: [Object] },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  }
}
```

The connection is then handled like this:

```
module.exports.io = socketio(httpsServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});

module.exports.io.adapter(ioredis({ host: config.redis.hostname, port: config.redis.port }));
var redisClient = redis.createClient(config.redis.port, config.redis.hostname);

module.exports.io.use(function (socket, handler) {
  console.log('The namespace middleware is registered');
  console.log(socket.request.headers.cookie);
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) {
    socket.request.cookies = cookie.parse(decodeURIComponent(socket.request.headers.cookie));
    socket.request.sessionID = socket.request.cookies['PHPSESSID'];
    socket.request.socketSessionId = socket.request.cookies['socketSessionId'];
    console.log("Authorization attempt with sessionID: " + socket.request.sessionID + " and socketSessionId: " + socket.request.socketSessionId);
    redisClient.get("PHPREDIS_SESSION:" + socket.request.sessionID, function (error, reply) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("The redis client had an error: " + error);
        return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because the redis client had an error.'));
      } else if (!reply) {
        console.log('The connection was refused because the redis client did not find the sessionID.');
        return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because the redis client did not find the sessionID.'));
      } else {
        var redisSocketSessionId = utils.getRedisValue(reply, "socketSessionId");
        if ('undefined' == typeof socket.request.socketSessionId || redisSocketSessionId != socket.request.socketSessionId) {
          console.log('The connection was refused because the socketSessionId was invalid.');
          return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because the socketSessionId was invalid.'));
        } else {
          console.log('The connection was granted.');
          handler();
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('The connection was refused because no cookie was transmitted.');
    return handler(new Error('The connection was refused because no cookie was transmitted.'));
  }
});
```

The client connection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var elearningSocket;
$(function() {
  if ('undefined' != typeof io && 'undefined' == typeof elearningSocket) {
    console.log("Creating a socket on //dev.learnintouch.com:9001/elearning");
    elearningSocket = io.connect('//dev.learnintouch.com:9001/elearning', { reconnect: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });
  }
  if ('undefined' != typeof elearningSocket) {
    console.log("A socket on //dev.learnintouch.com:9001/elearning has been created");
    elearningSocket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log("The elearning namespace socket connected");
      elearningSocket.emit('watchLiveCopilot', {'elearningSubscriptionId': '63', 'elearningClassId': '7'});
    });
    elearningSocket.on('postLogin', function(data) {
      isAdmin = data.admin;
    });
    elearningSocket.on('message', function(message) {
      console.log(message);
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

And the Chrome browser console:

```
Creating a socket on //dev.learnintouch.com:9001/elearning
A socket on //dev.learnintouch.com:9001/elearning has been created
```

But when sending a client connection, the log never shows the `The namespace middleware is registered` message.

Versions:

```
http@0.0.1-security
https@1.0.0
socket.io@4.1.3
cors@2.8.5
redis@3.1.2
socket.io-redis@6.1.1
connect@3.7.0
cookie@0.4.1
lodash@4.17.21
```

It looks like the connection cannot be established.

After a while the browser console shows an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE message as in:

```
socket.io.min.js:6 GET http://dev.learnintouch.com:9001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbGNn6V net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

But the NodeJS socket server seems to be listening:

```
netstat -l | grep 9001
tcp6       0      0 [::]:9001               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

The NodeJS socket server is not reachable.

But the firewall seems not to be the issue:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
9001                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

The error can be seen live at
http://www.europasprak.com/elearning/subscription/2938/course

by first logging at
http://www.europasprak.com/engine/modules/user/login.php

with using the user `demo@demo.com` with the `demo` password.

UPDATE: I could solve the issue. It related to a handler preventing the connection from being established.
When changing the following:

```
module.exports.io.use((socket, handler) => {
```

to the following:

```
module.exports.io.of('/elearning').use((socket, handler) => {
```

the connection could then be done.

Comment: The demo site gives a CORS error, and not the error mentioned in this question. Is this question still relevant? I see that another question has been posted about the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444494/how-to-have-socket-io-on-a-custom-node-server-accept-cors-requests

Comment: @Mehdi They are two different questions. The one about the CORS error occurs only on my local dev environment. This one does not show me the same error. In fact now, this one shows me the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Comment: Error message displayed in Firefox: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.europasprak.com:9001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbB6hWo. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

Comment: You might want socket.io client to use port 80, then reverse proxy to port 9001.

Comment: @Mehdi Now I, too, see the CORS error.

Comment: I think it's not really a CORS issue, in spite of the message, because the `curl "http://dev.learnintouch.com:9001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"` request gets a 404 response.

Comment: I fixed the CORS issue. Now I am faced with a 404 response status code.

Comment: I also fixed the 404 issue. I was returning a 404 from my HTTP server handler. I also added the handler code in the question.

Comment: It seems that all problems are solved, then? You may delete the question if it is the case. Otherwise, please edit the question to describe the current problem.

Comment: @Mehdi I'm still fighting with this `socket.io` server implementation. I shall follow your advice and update the question then.

Comment: @Stephane I'm unclear on which issue is still causing a problem? I'm just seeing ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when I call `eLearningSocket = io.connect('http://dev.learnintouch.com:9001/elearning', { reconnect: true, rejectUnauthorized: false });`

Comment: aren't use supposed to use `elearningSocket.on('connection', function() {...})` instead of `elearningSocket.on('connect', function() {...})`

Comment: @NathanTM Both work. I tend to use on('connect', () => {}).

Comment: Ping the hostname "dev.learnintouch.com" and check if it is resolved by your DNS server and has an IP address.

Comment: @raxetul You mean something like this ? `stephane@stephane-pc:~$ ping dev.learnintouch.com
PING dev.learnintouch.com (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from stephane-pc (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
64 bytes from stephane-pc (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.107 ms`

Comment: The whole issue is in fact the socket server not responding.

Answer (score 1):

you need to determine whether the `socket.io` connection is successful, and then add events such as `cores, adapters, events etc...`to track down the problem step by step.

judging from the error report you provided above, `socket.io` was not established successfully.

Comment: @Stephane  I saw your updated code, did it solve your problem?